# Drawing Marbles, Consecutive Colors

Tags: probability

We have a bag of 10 marbles - 3 red, 2 black, 3 green, 2 white.  If we draw all 10 without replacement, what's the probability we draw either the 3 red or 3 green consecutively?

I started with a simpler problem I think I've solved, but can't seem to extend it to the example above: We have a bag of 5 marbles, 3 red and 2 black.  If we draw all 5, what's the probability we draw the 3 red consecutively?  For this, there are
$$
{5 \choose {3,2}} = 10
$$
combinations of 3 red and 2 black.  Visually, the 3 red will be in consecutive order in 3 of these combinations:
$$
RRRBB, BRRRB, BBRRR,
$$
hence the probability is $\frac{3}{10}$.

For the 10 marble problem, I started with number of ways to draw them, which I think is
$$
{10 \choose {3,2,3,2}} = 25200.
$$
But, I'm having trouble computing the number of ways to draw 3 consecutive red or green.

Comment: Seems like the [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). There is some number $A$ of all outcomes, $R$ of which contain 3 red marbles in a row (treat those three as one then), $G$ contain 3 green in a row and some $H$ contain both 3 red in a row *and* 3 green in a row (those are equivalent to drawing from a bag with 6 marbles, 2 of which are distinct from remaining 4); then the answer is $A-R-G+H$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of three consecutive marbles with the same color as one big element.

$rrrgggbbww$

Let $rrr=R$. Then you have $Rgggbbww$

Here you have $\binom{8}{1,3,2,2}$ ways of arrangement.

Let $ggg=G$ and leave $rrr$ unchanged: $rrrGbbww$

Here you have $\binom{8}{1,3,2,2}$ ways of arrangement too.

To avoid double counting you have to subtract the case if $rrr=R$ and $ggg=G$:

$RGbbww$

Here you have $\binom{6}{1,1,2,2}$ ways of arrangement.

You have to add the two first results and substract the third result. After that you divide the result by the number of all possible ways of arrangement:

$\binom{10}{3,3,2,2}$